# How to print value without if else

Tags: php, if-statement, get, logic

```
echo result(1);

function reslut($num) 
{ if($num == 1) return 0; if($num == 0) return 1;

}
```

How can I do this without using an `if` or `else` statement?

Comment: Notice your `reslut` function has no arguments.  You probably wanted `$num`.

Comment: And `result` is a different function name to `reslut`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `?:` operator as follows:

```
$num == 1 ? when_true_expression : when_false_expression;
```

You can nest this operator.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a `!` in the function like this as if the variable in question is either 1 or 0 its basically a boolean

```
function result($num) 
{ 
    return (int)!$num;
}

$t = 0;
$t = result($t);
echo $t . PHP_EOL;
$t = result($t);
echo $t . PHP_EOL;
$t = result($t);
echo $t . PHP_EOL;
$t = result($t);
echo $t . PHP_EOL;
```

Result:

```
1
0
1
0
```

Comment: This answer is perfect for us

Answer (score 0):

I've adjusted your function - given it the name `result` and added the argument `$num`.

Notice how it actually has three possible return values: 0, 1 and null.

Because you don't use the identical comparison operator (rather you use the equal comparison operator), output might not be what you expect as Php may do some type juggling.

I've added a function that given an input of 1 will return 0, and given an input of 0 will return 1, any other input will return null.

```
<?php
// Your function.
function result($num) 
{ 
    if($num == 1)
        return 0;
    if($num == 0)
        return 1;
}

function swap_one_and_zero($num) 
{
    return in_array($num, [1,0], true) ? $num ^ 1 : null; 
}

$tests = [-1, 0, 1, 1.1, 2, 'a', 'foo', null];

var_export(
    array_map('result', $tests)
);

var_export(
    array_map('swap_one_and_zero',$tests)
);
```

Output arrays:

```
array (
  0 => NULL,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 0,
  3 => NULL,
  4 => NULL,
  5 => 1,
  6 => 1,
  7 => 1,
)

array (
  0 => NULL,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 0,
  3 => NULL,
  4 => NULL,
  5 => NULL,
  6 => NULL,
  7 => NULL,
)
```

I've used a contracted if else statement with the ternary operator.  And used the xor bitwise operator to flip between 1 and 0.

If you are allergic to ifs, you could replace your function with a like for like using switch statements:

```
function result($num) 
{
    switch($num) {
        case 1:
            return 0;
            break;
        case 0:
            return 1;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Using ternary operator, you can do that but you can only define one condition

Comment: This is really only a comment. To make it an answer at least show an example

Comment: @vikrammistry It's up to you if you want to post an answer. But stop assuming that posting the equivalent of "Google it" is a reasonable answer.

Comment: Being a developer, you should stop spoon feeding. In the future, your colleagues will simply show you the way. They will not write the code for u. It's upon you what your thinking. :)

Comment: @vikrammistry This is not a tutorial site; it's a question-and-answer site. You have a simple choice: provide an answer, or don't.